# Why am I getting the record added again after deleting it

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a button, which calls the delete function when clicking on it:

```
deleteRecord = (id) => {
  return this._entriesRef.doc(id).delete()
}
```

And in the DataStore, I have a event listener, which listens for the change of the snapshot:

```
snapshot.docChanges.forEach((change) => {
  if (change.type === 'added') {
    this[this._category].unshift({
      ...change.doc.data(),
      id: change.doc.id
    })
  } else if (change.type === 'removed') {
    this[this._category] = this[this._category].filter((log) => {
      return log.id !== change.doc.id
    })
  }
}, this)
```

However, using breakpoints I can see that after the deletion happens, it first goes to the `removed` if statement, which is as expected, **but then added the same record(with the same id) back to the data**.

How could that happen?

Comment: Is the document added to the database again, or just displayed again despite being deleted?

Comment: I think it was being added to the database because the "added" snapshot event was triggered again.

Comment: So when you go to the console, you can see the data? Sorry if that seems like an obvious question. Just want to clarify.

Comment: Yes, that's really weird. Actually I don't think the screenshots are gonna help much. It's just the execution flow goes to `change.type === 'added'` after `change.type === 'removed'`

Comment: But if you need further clarification, I'm sure willing to post some more info. @JenPerson Thanks!!

Comment: @JenPerson I accidentally solved that by adding a `event.preventDefault()` to the button click event. Really weird. I'll spare some time to try to make a fiddle addressing that issue.